# Apache2 Virtual Host redirect except on special path

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect, url

Assume we have 2 domains.

```
www.my-domain.com
www.mydomain.com
```

As Standard, we have a redirection from *.mydomain.com/* to *.my-domain.com/* via

```
(mydomain.conf)
<Virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com *.mydomain.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+\.)?mydomain\.com(\/.+)?$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%1my-domain.com$2$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

But now, due to backwards compability, we have one special URL "www.mydomain.com/special/task.php" which needs to be served directly and should not be redirected.

What i am trying to do ist something like this:

```
(mydomain.conf)
<Virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerPath /special/
  DocumentRoot /var/www/special/
</VirtualHost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com *.mydomain.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+\.)?mydomain\.com(\/.+)?$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.*) http://%1my-domain.com$2$1 [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

But this wont work.
What am i doing wrong or is this even possible? What do i have to do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add another `RewriteCond` behind your existing one to implement this exception. Like this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/special/task.php [NC]`

Note, that by default, all `RewiteCond`s are connected with logical AND. So the `RewriteRule` is triggered only if all `RewriteCond`s evaluate to true.

Comment: How do i add the DocumentRoot then? Just add it aftwerwards and it will be used, since the second RewriteRule does not redirect the call?

Comment: Sry, i forgot to think. I will add this, and this Condition eliminates the following Redirection if its false(!true) AND then serves the content as defined by the embedded DocumentRoot.